# JBPM Data Input Output settings in Drools Guvnor

Tags: jbpm

Can any one explain how to use Input Output mappings in Drools Guvnor?

How to access task form information from next task form in jbpm 5.4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use output mapping to copy the task result to a process variable on the first task, use an input mapping to copy the process variable to a task input on the second task.